# SIMD (AVX) compare

Tags: c, gcc, sse, simd

What is the name of `gcc`'s intrinsic for comparing `__m256` and `__m256i` (AVX instruction set)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As said in the [Intel AVX documentation](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-advanced-vector-extensions/)

```
_mm256_cmp_ps, _mm256_cmp_pd
```

etc

Note that instead of having multiple comparison instructions, you have to pass an enum indicating the comparison done. E.g :

```
res = _mm256_cmp_ps(a,b, _CMP_LT_OQ); // AVX res = a < b
```

Comment: Thank you, and what about comparing `__m256i` type? Those two functions only handle `__m256` and `__m256d`?

Comment: IIRC, there is none, you have to use _mm256_extractf128_si256 to extarct integers into float then use the others

Comment: So there is no fast way how to compare two `int []` (arrays of ints of length 8) using `__mm256`? I mean using the classic `load, cmp...` scenario.

Comment: @James, AVX never fully supported operations on `__m256i`. That will come in AVX2.

Comment: Next to that, handlign char in vector context is often lackluster anyway as the dynamic of the value range is clamped to 8 bits. 16 bits vector starts to be interesting and so does 32 bits one.